# Node.js equivalent data types for python's list, tuple and dictionary

Tags: python, node.js, list, dictionary, tuples

For anyone migrating from python to node.js, it will be useful to know the equivalent data types in node.js for lists, tuples and dictionaries.

Do they exist? If not, are there node.js modules to achieve equivalent data structures in node.js?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Where Python has lists, JavaScript has *arrays*. These are declared using the exact same syntax as Python, with square brackets and commas:

```
var names = ["Foo", "Bar", "Baz"];
names[0]; # Foo
```

As an alternative to dictionaries you can use *associative arrays*, which are actually just JavaScript objects. Again, the syntax is similar to Python:

```
var dictionary = {"name": "Foo", "email": "foo@bar.com"};
dictionary["name"]; # Foo
```

JavaScript doesn't have tuples, but there is a [tuple library on NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tuple), although I've never used it.

If you want to experiment with arrays and associative arrays, I'd recommend [repl.it](https://repl.it/languages/javascript) - the right-hand column is a REPL (read-eval-print loop), just like Python's equivalent when you open a terminal and type `py`.

Comment: Thanks. I think tuples are redundant if lists are available. Seems like javascript is good enough.

Comment: @user1824987 Lists are usually sufficient. Remember to accept my answer if it's helped you!